# How to select nth item from unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select the 3rd item in an unordered list but am having trouble doing so. I'm trying to get just 'Item 3' to return. Below is what I have that isn't working.  Any advice?

```
$("#sortable :nth-child(3)").val;
```

unordered list:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're using `.val` when it's actually `.val()` but you want to use `.text()` or `.html()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `$("#sortable :nth-child(3)").text();`

You are not using the right syntax, you'd have to add parentheses like so [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and call that on the list item, but the list item does not have a value defined. It would have worked if you had specified a value on the list item:

```
<li class="ui-state-default" value="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
```

Since you are after the text from inside the element, use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Note: `.val()` would have worked only if the value was numeric. It's strange, but `value` is a valid attribute for list items, provided the attribute's value is numeric (and jQuery seems to honor that). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and select by index:

`$($("#sortable").children()[2])`